# Delete a specific user from List by using SQL in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have wrote those lines of code to be able to add something in my SQL DB by using "external" values. Does anyone knows how can I delete something from my DB by using again external values?

My Code to add:

```
String UserName = "AnyName";
String UserAge = "AnyAge";

try {

     myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR, age VARCHAR)");

     SQLiteStatement statement = myDatabase.compileStatement("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES(?, ?)");

     statement.bindString(1, UserName);
     statement.bindString(2, UserAge);

     statement.execute();

}catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly delete with `database` instance using `delete` method like below

```
String UserName = "AnyName";
String UserAge = "AnyAge";
myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
myDatabase.delete("users", "name =? AND age =?" , new String[]{UserName, UserAge});
```